# MySQL Daemon failed to start on CentOS 6 after automatic update

Tags: mysql

MySQL suddenly stopped working this night, after an automatic update of MySQL.

```
[root@lincl1161 xxxx]# service mysqld restart
mysqld stopped:                                            [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
mysqld started:                                            [FAILED]
```

Here is my mysql.log file:

```
[root@lincl1161 xxxx]# tail /var/log/mysqld.log
170314  3:41:06 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
170314  3:41:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Killing the scheduler thread, thread id 1
170314  3:41:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Waiting for the scheduler thread to reply
170314  3:41:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Stopped
170314  3:41:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 2 events
170314  3:41:08 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3233579  user: 'admin'
170314  3:41:08 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3233578  user: 'admin'
170314  3:41:08 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3233575  user: 'admin'
170314  3:41:08 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3233574  user: 'admin'
170314  3:41:09  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170314  3:41:09  InnoDB: Waiting for 48 pages to be flushed
170314  3:41:10  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 53460683633
170314  3:41:10 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
170314 03:41:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

And the YUM log (the server uses Plesk):

```
[root@lincl1161 xxxx]# tail /var/log/yum.log
Jan 15 04:30:07 Updated: httpd-tools-2.2.15-56.el6.centos.3.x86_64
Jan 15 04:30:08 Updated: httpd-2.2.15-56.el6.centos.3.x86_64
Jan 15 04:30:08 Updated: 1:mod_ssl-2.2.15-56.el6.centos.3.x86_64
Jan 31 03:47:55 Updated: policycoreutils-2.0.83-30.1.el6_8.x86_64
Jan 31 03:48:07 Updated: selinux-policy-3.7.19-292.el6_8.2.noarch
Jan 31 03:48:45 Updated: selinux-policy-targeted-3.7.19-292.el6_8.2.noarch
Jan 31 03:48:49 Updated: psa-phpmyadmin-4.6.6-cos6.build1205170125.17.noarch
Jan 31 03:49:52 Updated: psa-selinux-12.5.30-cos6.build1205170125.17.noarch
Mar 14 03:40:51 Updated: mysql-libs-5.5.54-36.x86_64
Mar 14 03:40:54 Updated: mysql-5.5.54-36.x86_64
Mar 14 03:41:06 Updated: mysql-server-5.5.54-36.x86_64
```

No manual changes in server nor Plesk configurations have been made since months. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure admin stuff. The DBA site is better suited to handle such questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Daemon failed to start on CentOS 6 Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781217/mysql-daemon-failed-to-start-on-centos-6-server)

Answer (score 1):

That issue is related to a broken update by Plesk.

Please read the article https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001906725 .

You can fix it by running this command:

```
install -m 0700 -o mysql -g mysql -d /var/lib/mysql-files
```

and start mysql:

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question

Comment: Thank you for the link. I couldn't find anything on how to mark this question as duplicate since it's hidden in the "Flag" section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I finally resolved the issue by upgrading MySQL to 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

We finally resolved the issue by upgrading MySQL to 5.6.